# Bitmap is not on canvas after drawing

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am drawing a Bitmap with `canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);` to my canvas and the bitmap will just not show. Any ideas?

Thank you!

```
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myfile.getPath());
            //Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);

            Log.i(TAG, "builded Bitmap");               
            Log.i(TAG, "scaling bitmap...");


            //int scale;
            //Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            //matrix.setScale(0.1F, 0.1F);
            //if (bmp.getWidth() < bmp.getHeight()){
            //  scale = canvas.getWidth()/bmp.getWidth();
            //}else{
            //  scale = canvas.getHeight()/bmp.getHeight();
            //}
            //matrix.postScale(scale, scale, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
            //matrix.postScale(0.5F, canvas.getWidth()/bmp.getWidth());

            //Bitmap bmp2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), true);

            //Paint p = new Paint();
            //p.setFilterBitmap(true);


            //try{
            bmp  = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), true);
            Log.i(TAG, "scaled");
            Log.i(TAG, "showing bitmap...");
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
            Log.i(TAG, "showed bitmap");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you draw a line?
Either call invalidate() or postInvalidate().

Read Drawing here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

And copy some examples like:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html

Comment: if i draw a line after drawing the bitmap it works! i can not call invalidate on the view because i habe no view, its a live background

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess:

Instead of "Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myfile.getPath());
" try "Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(..);"

Comment: `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` is a workaround because of this bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066